# Load models in TensorFlow by memory directly

Tags: tensorflow, go

I'm using Go and this [library](https://github.com/wamuir/graft) to use TensorFlow there. I wonder if it is possible to load the models from memory instead from the file. I mean right now I have the following code:

```
model, err := tf.LoadSavedModel(cfg.ModelPath, tags, nil)
```

And what I would like to have is something like:

```
model, err := tf.LoadModelFromMemory(modelInBytes, tags, nil)
```

One solution we though in our team is build TensorFlow from code and modify it, but that approach supposes many changes and a hard way to get it, so I would like if there is something already done.

Comment: what is `modelInBytes`?  Just the contents of the file at cfg.ModelPath?

Comment: Hi @dave, exactly is basically the model content that I load previously and I want to  use it.